# Campaign Link with itms-apps:

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

With App Analytics I created a Campaign Link for my app (`https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id[AppId]?pt=[ProviderId]&ct=[Campaign]&mt=8`).
Now I want to use it in my app to link to another app. Will it works correctly if I just replace `https:` to `itms-apps:`?

My previous link was `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?type=Purple+Software&id=[myApp]`

Comment: Have you tried using the campaign link directly? It looks like the https will be needed (not sure, though) so it may be trackable by the analytics...

Comment: How about simply trying things?

Comment: I'm going to do this.